# Overloaded function gets ignored by compiler when using enums C++

Tags: c++, enums

Let's say I have two functions, one accepts template arguments, the second one accepts uint8_t and converts it to int for the sake of being outputted correctly.
The problem I'm facing is that if the uint8_t is an enum and it is passed to the function it will be treated as a template argument. How can I ensure that the overloaded function will be called? (Without using enum class). Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template<typename T>
void myFunc(const T& value) {
    std::cout << "template "<< value;
}
void myFunc(uint8_t value) {
    std::cout << (int)value;
}

enum : uint8_t {
    ORANGE = 0,
    APPLE
};

int main()
{
    myFunc(APPLE);

    return 0;
}
```

Current Output:

```
template 1
```

Comment: Just cast the argument to the type uint8_t.

Comment: myFunc(static_cast<uint8_t>(APPLE));

Comment: `APPLE` isn't a `uint8_t`.  An implicit conversion exists, but the template is an exact match, so it's the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 you can do as follows:

```
template<typename T>
requires (!std::is_enum_v<T>)
void myFunc(const T& value) {
    std::cout << "template "<< value;
}
```

Or with `std::enable_if` in C++11 and above (the code below requires C++17 due to shortcuts but can be easily converted to C++11):

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum_v<T>>>
void myFunc(const T& value) {
    std::cout << "template "<< value;
}
```